# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter database exception

Tags: android, firebaseui

I created a model class and layout for single item and then created view holder and firebaseRecyclerAdapter as shown in code below and when I run it gives me this error

```
        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't 
        convert object of type java.lang.String to type 
        com.best.karem.letsplay.Model.PsModel
```

I tried adding onValueEventListener but it is not working too

## Model Class

```
      public class PsModel {

private String title;
private String location;
private String thumb_image;


public PsModel(String title, String location, String thumb_image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.location = location;
    this.thumb_image = thumb_image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getThumb_image() {
    return thumb_image;
}

public void setThumb_image(String thumb_image) {
    this.thumb_image = thumb_image;
}

public PsModel(){

}


}
```

## Main Class

```
       public class Ps extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private FloatingActionButton psBtn;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private DatabaseReference psRef;
private String currentUser;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PsModel , PsViewHolder> adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ps);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    psRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(currentUser).child("Ps");


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.ps_recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PsModel, PsViewHolder>(
            PsModel.class,
            R.layout.list_item,
            PsViewHolder.class,
            psRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PsViewHolder viewHolder, PsModel model, int position) {


            viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.itemLocation.setText(model.getLocation());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getThumb_image()).into(viewHolder.itemImage);

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public static class PsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView itemImage;
    public TextView itemTitle , itemLocation;

    public PsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        itemLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_location);



    }
}
```

[**FIREBASE DATA STRUCTURE IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQWVJ.png)

and Please don't refer me to another answer on this site because I searched for this for 4 hours and tried everything and didn't work

Comment: Can you please check if any of the variables of `title`, `location` and `thumb_image` in Firebase `Ps` has any other type other than String? I think one of these three is not a String type field hence this error.

Comment: Also, if still error occurs, include a snapshot of the database structure please.

Comment: I included it in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the content of psRef?

I understand it's coming as String and expected as an object.

```
 psRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(currentUser).child("Ps");
```

Comment: I added an image for firebase data structure and I think when I wrote them to data base they were String

Comment: So you now know what was the cause of the error. Delete the entries and try again. Feel free to vote up if answer helps and accept if worked for you.

Comment: It is in String where is the Error?